# Who are the villains in this picture?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

I'm watching Justice League Season 4 Episode 1: The Cat and the Canary, the bad guy at the front of that group about to attack Black Canary is Atomic Skull.

The image isn't the best but can anyone tell me who the rest of the bad guys are?

I'm aware they may just be made up background villains for this particular episode, but since there are so many DC characters to pick from, I'm guessing they're canon.

[image]

Comment: Mindlessly, I tried clicking play.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From left to right:

- [Sportsmaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportsmaster)
- [Gork](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Gork) or [Amygdala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdala_(comics)) (see comments)
- [Tracer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracer_(DC_Comics))
- [Atomic Skull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Skull)
- [Evil Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Star)
- [Electrocutioner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocutioner)
- [Hellgrammite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellgrammite_(comics))

All information found from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(DC_Comics)#Television).

> They were forced to battle other participants of Meta-Brawl including Sportsmaster, Bloodsport, Electrocutioner, Atomic Skull, Hellgrammite, Tracer, Evil Star, and Amygdala.

Comment: Excellent! Cheers Jack

Comment: Sportsmaster, the world's deadliest man with a red rubber ball and a whistle.

Comment: That wiki article now says Gork, rather than Amygdala.

Comment: DC wiki agrees: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Gork_(DCAU)

Comment: Although, of course, the issue is that both are user-editable.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The DC wiki specifically says that it's conjecture based on appearances, and that the villain was never named in the cartoon. I think it represents the best guess of the community as a whole, meaning that the wiki is working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The second figure from the left might be a very, VERY minor Batman villain, [Gork](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Gork), who appeared in Detective Comics #480.

[image: Gork cover]

Comment: I add a link to the DCAU wiki and an image of the cover of the book in question. If someone has an image from within, that would probably be better.